# Using recursive SQL command without using recursion (as in SQL3)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables:

person(pid, name,email,phone,city)

ride(rid,pid,date,spots,start,target) [rideID, personID- the person who offers the ride, spots= open slots in the ride, start and target are the destinations]

participate(pid,rid)- person pid participates in ride rid

I have to satisfy the function generousUsers(k)

generosity ranking is defined by the number of rides the person offers.
I have to find the Kth generous users by this definition (there may be more than one) or return NULL if we have less than K people on the list.

I was thinking of using VIEW but the recursive nature of the query leaves me clueless.

Comment: If a person participates in a ride, does that count minus?

Comment: The personID in ride is the offerer/driver, while the personID in participate is the accepter/passenger ?

Comment: it doesn't count as minus, i'm using PSQL, the PID in ride is indeed the offerer and pid in participate are the passengers

Comment: Well, it appears your formula only needs the ride table, since the passengers in the particpate table are not counted, or are they? Please define the calculation(s) that generousUsers() is based upon.

Comment: I guess your right, we don't need the participate table. I just have to find the Kth "generous" user.

Comment: In my answer I have included a solution for PostGreSQL. In order for an answer to be complete (especially for the NULL part) you need to specify the environment and programming language you're developing in.
But I think you 'll get an idea of what your query should look like.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Since you are using PostgreSQL The equivalent of ROWNUM would be row_number()
Which would be used like this:

```
Select pid From 
    (Select pid, count(*) as ranking, row_number() OVER (Order By ranking Desc) as Rownum 
    From Ride 
    Group By pid
    Order By ranking desc)
    Where Rownum < K
```

---

**INITIAL ANSWER**

If you need their pid only then you can try this.

```
Select pid From 
(Select pid, count(*) as ranking 
From Ride 
Group By pid
Order By ranking desc)
Where Rownum < K
```

This way you get the K first pids based on their ranking.
Now if you have less than K you will still get them.
But depending on what environment you're developing you can use a simple count to check that.

Something like

```
Select Count(*) 
From (Select Distinct pid 
    From Ride)
```

where you get how many Distinct pids have offered a ride. 
You check this number to be >= K and you're set.

**IMPORTANT**: The RowNum function will not work on every type of RDBMS (It's for Oracle) but there are of course replacements everywhere (like LIMIT etc).

Comment: But it gives me K values for the table, how do I extract the Kth person (or if they have equal rankind, extract all the people tied at Kth).

Comment: @JennyB Oh you need the Kth only? Thats not hard I'll edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: @JennyB if you want more than one Kth user it gets a bit more complicated though. Because now suddenly you need to group people with the same rankings. Meaning people tied up at first spot etc etc Let me think about it.

Comment: I also have to sort the tied-Kth users by the date of their earliest ride offered so the user who offered the most early date in the database is the first from the people tied at the Kth place.